# R read.table txt file error

Tags: r

I have a really bizzare error which has started to occur but to my knowledge nothing in my process has changed.

I am reading in a text file that has 38 columns, always has, I then check to make sure all columns are there using read.table.

```
LocLines <- read.table(paste(ImportFolder,ImportFileList[i],sep = ""), sep = "\t",header=T,strip.white=T,quote = "\"",colClasses="character")
```

Now I am getting an error saying this is no longer the case

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
line 1 did not have 38 elements
```

I open the txt file in excel and there are 38 column headers, I have changed the files to CSV and there is no error when using read.lines I am wondering if there is some property within the txt file I am not aware of that is causing the number not to match 38? Is it being read in and are there 'hidden' columns?

If anyone could shed some light on this or can think of a way to check the txt file in another way before I read it in that would be great.

ANSWER: There was a '#' in the underlying data in the .txt file which was causing the issue, question answered by DWin

Comment: try `readLines` to troubleshoot.  see what you get.

Comment: Which OS are you using? It could have something to do with line-endings or encoding (Latin/UTF-8) if the file has been exchanged between Windows and Linux.

Comment: Open the file in a text editor. Excel has a penchant for mangling text files.

Comment: I have header=T currently so that it points towards the header in the text file, so as far as I am aware that should point towards the column headers

Comment: opened in Tinn-r 38 column headers, although the underlying data does not sit under those headers, not sure if that has any meaning?

Comment: read lines gives me 38 headers spaced with \t

Comment: Unmatched quotes and octothorpes "#" are common causes of file corruption. I was also supriced by you choice of separator between foldename and file name, but maybe you had a trailing"/" in the folder.

Comment: DWin thats it there is a # lower down in the dataset have removed it and added replace funtion to remove them in the future. How do I give you credit for answering the questions?